# Spring tries to initialize AutoConfiguration beans using default constructor

Tags: spring-boot

We are having issues starting up our Spring Boot Web application. The main problem to properly diagnose the startup is that it only seems to happen in 1% of the startups. In 99% of the startup procedures all works fine and we end up having a properly working spring boot application. However in those 1% of those cases we see issues like this:

```
WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'errorPageFilterRegistration' defined in org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.Error
PageFilterConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'errorPageFilterRegistration' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'errorPageFilter' defined in org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilterConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.spring
framework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigu
re.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.<init>() []
```

For some reason it tries to initialize AutoConfiguration beans by using a default constructor which obviously is not present. There is a constructor present which should be autowired.
Also the AutoConfiguration that is in the stacktrace can be different. Sometimes it is another one like e.g. `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration`

Any help or ideas on why this could be happening is appreciated. As this happens very occasionally this is hard to debug as we cannot relyably reproduce. Note that the stacktrace does not contain any custom code. Our application is quite big and we rely mostly on @Configuration classes to do configure the Beans.

Why would spring attempt to initialize an AutoConfiguration bean with a default constructor ?

The errorPageFilterConfiguration source of spring looks like this:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class ErrorPageFilterConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ErrorPageFilter errorPageFilter() {
        return new ErrorPageFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean<ErrorPageFilter> errorPageFilterRegistration(ErrorPageFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<ErrorPageFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
        registration.setOrder(filter.getOrder());
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ASYNC);
        return registration;
    }

}
```

According to the stack on creation of the errorPageFilter it is initializing the ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration as a prerequisite ? Why ?
We are not initializing these beans manually. The only relevant code for error page handling that we have is this following:

```
    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
        return webServerFactory -> {
            ErrorPage errorPage = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/error");
            webServerFactory.addErrorPages(errorPage);
        };
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the init code of:  errorPageFilterRegistration?  

I believe it's some code error.

Comment: @SeanH We are actually not initializing this ourselves, this is all based on autoconfiguration. Now this makes me wonder.... From the stack it appears to be trying to initialize first the 'errorPageFilterRegistration' and then the errorPageFilter. But why would it then require to 'initialize' the ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration ??

Comment: The ErrorPageFilterRegistration is only registered when starting as a standalone war. This is all arranged by the spring framework. Explained in the javadoc on top of org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter

Comment: BTW,  are you using spring-boot + spring cloud?

Comment: Only spring-boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Spring framework, introduced in version 5.3 in AbstractBeanFactory.

BeanPostProcessorCacheAwareList and accesses to the beanPostProcessors instance are not Thread safe. If multiple Threads are running during initialization and a Thread calls getBeanPostProcessorCache() while another Thread is calling addBeanPostProcessors, you can create a cache which does not contain all BeanPostProcessor instances and thus doesn't find the appropriate constructor.

I will submit a bug for this to spring-framework.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/16ea4692bab551800b9ba994ac08099e8acfd6cd/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanFactory.java#L964

Issue created : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29299